# Issue in handling Http Response with status: 200 from an Angular 6

Tags: php, angular, typescript, angular6, angular-errorhandler

As I tried to upload an image via API scripted in PHP, once after uploading succeded into the following directory getting `HttpErrorResponse` code with `status: 200`

**upload-image.component.ts**

```
OnSubmit(Caption,Image){
   this.imageService.postFile(Caption.value,this.fileToUpload)
   .subscribe(
     data =>{
      // this.heroes.push(hero);
       console.log(data);
       Caption.value = null;
       Image.value = null;
       this.imageUrl = "/assets/img/default-image.png";
     },
     err => {
       this.errorMsg = <any>err;
       console.log(err);
     }
   );
}
```

**upload-image.service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
...

postFile(caption: string, fileToUpload: File): Observable<any> {
    const endpoint = 'http://localhost/angular6/fileUpload.php';
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('selectFile', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
    formData.append('ImageCaption', caption);
    return this.http
      .post<any>(endpoint, formData)
      .pipe(tap(
        res=>{
          console.log('server data '+res)
        },
        catchError( this._errorHandler)
        // err=> console.log(err)
      ))
}

private _errorHandler(error: Response) {
    console.error('Error Occured: ' + error);
    return Observable.throw(error || 'Some Error on Server Occured');

}
```

But the image was uploading successfully. But even after the upload is completed, as I'm getting HTTP error response

By looking at the above two codes by consoling the logs generated after submit is as follows:

> **`catchError(this._errorHandler)`** i.e, by catching the error from
>   the console prints like this below

```
TypeError: source.lift is not a function
    at TapSubscriber.catchErrorOperatorFunction [as _tapError] (catchError.js:8)
    at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._error (tap.js:55)
    at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/OuterSubscriber.js.OuterSubscriber.notifyError (OuterSubscriber.js:13)
    at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._error (InnerSubscriber.js:18)
    at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
```

> **`err => console.log(err)`** Results in HttpErrorResponse

```
upload-image.component.ts:42 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost/angular6/fileUpload.php", ok: false, …}
error:
error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token h in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:7454:51) at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2743:31) at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:36912:33) at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2742:36) at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2510:47) at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2818:34) at invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3862:14) at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3888:17)
message: "Unexpected token h in JSON at position 0"
stack: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token h in JSON at position 0↵    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)↵    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:7454:51)↵    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2743:31)↵    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:36912:33)↵    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2742:36)↵    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2510:47)↵    at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2818:34)↵    at invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3862:14)↵    at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3888:17)"
__proto__: Error
constructor: ƒ SyntaxError()
message: ""
name: "SyntaxError"
toString: ƒ toString()
__proto__: Object
text: "http://localhost/angular4/uploads/153744221629Koala.jpg"
__proto__: Object
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost/angular4/fileUpload.php"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://localhost/angular4/fileUpload.php"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

How am I supposed to code in order to handle and get successful Http Response message with the name of the image that was successfully uploaded?

### Edited:

```
$ npm list --depth=0
image-upload@0.0.0 C:\xampp\htdocs\imageUpload
+-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.8.3
+-- @angular/animations@6.1.8
+-- @angular/cli@6.2.3
+-- @angular/common@6.1.8
+-- @angular/compiler@6.1.8
+-- @angular/compiler-cli@6.1.8
+-- @angular/core@6.1.8
+-- @angular/forms@6.1.8
+-- @angular/http@6.1.8
+-- @angular/language-service@6.1.8
+-- @angular/platform-browser@6.1.8
+-- @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@6.1.8
+-- @angular/router@6.1.8
+-- @types/jasmine@2.8.8
+-- @types/jasminewd2@2.0.3
+-- @types/node@8.9.5
+-- codelyzer@4.3.0
+-- core-js@2.5.7
+-- jasmine-core@2.99.1
+-- jasmine-spec-reporter@4.2.1
+-- karma@3.0.0
+-- karma-chrome-launcher@2.2.0
+-- karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter@2.0.4
+-- karma-jasmine@1.1.2
+-- karma-jasmine-html-reporter@0.2.2
+-- materialize-css@1.0.0-rc.2
+-- protractor@5.4.1
+-- rxjs@6.2.2
+-- ts-node@7.0.1
+-- tslint@5.11.0
+-- typescript@2.9.2
`-- zone.js@0.8.26

npm ERR! missing: mkdirp@0.5.1, required by node-pre-gyp@0.10.0
npm ERR! missing: minimist@0.0.8, required by mkdirp@0.5.1
npm ERR! missing: minimatch@3.0.4, required by ignore-walk@3.0.1
npm ERR! missing: brace-expansion@1.1.11, required by minimatch@3.0.4
npm ERR! missing: balanced-match@1.0.0, required by brace-expansion@1.1.11
npm ERR! missing: concat-map@0.0.1, required by brace-expansion@1.1.11
npm ERR! missing: console-control-strings@1.1.0, required by npmlog@4.1.2
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by readable-stream@2.3.6
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by readable-stream@2.3.6
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by string_decoder@1.1.1
npm ERR! missing: console-control-strings@1.1.0, required by gauge@2.7.4
npm ERR! missing: string-width@1.0.2, required by gauge@2.7.4
npm ERR! missing: strip-ansi@3.0.1, required by gauge@2.7.4
npm ERR! missing: code-point-at@1.1.0, required by string-width@1.0.2
npm ERR! missing: is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0, required by string-width@1.0.2
npm ERR! missing: strip-ansi@3.0.1, required by string-width@1.0.2
npm ERR! missing: number-is-nan@1.0.1, required by is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0
npm ERR! missing: ansi-regex@2.1.1, required by strip-ansi@3.0.1
npm ERR! missing: string-width@1.0.2, required by wide-align@1.1.2
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by glob@7.1.2
npm ERR! missing: minimatch@3.0.4, required by glob@7.1.2
npm ERR! missing: once@1.4.0, required by glob@7.1.2
npm ERR! missing: once@1.4.0, required by inflight@1.0.6
npm ERR! missing: wrappy@1.0.2, required by inflight@1.0.6
npm ERR! missing: wrappy@1.0.2, required by once@1.4.0
npm ERR! missing: minipass@2.2.4, required by tar@4.4.1
npm ERR! missing: mkdirp@0.5.1, required by tar@4.4.1
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by tar@4.4.1
npm ERR! missing: yallist@3.0.2, required by tar@4.4.1
npm ERR! missing: minipass@2.2.4, required by fs-minipass@1.2.5
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by minipass@2.2.4
npm ERR! missing: yallist@3.0.2, required by minipass@2.2.4
npm ERR! missing: minipass@2.2.4, required by minizlib@1.1.0
```

---

```
$ ng update rxjs
WARNING: This command may not execute successfully. The package/collection may not support the 'targets' field within 'C:\xampp\htdocs\imageUpload\angular.json'. This can be corrected by renaming the following 'targets' fields to 'architect':
1) Line: 12; Column: 7
2) Line: 104; Column: 7
    Updating package.json with dependency rxjs @ "6.3.2" (was "6.2.2")...
UPDATE package.json (1355 bytes)

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

added 8 packages and updated 1 package in 310.507s
```

Comment: Can you try updating ***rxjs*** to the latest version

Comment: As I'm using the latest version of rxjs 6.2.2  @Thanthu

Comment: Looks like the latest version is 6.3.2

Comment: Upgraded to 6.3.2. Still, the same error persists. It might be with the coding part  @Thanthu